# Spring boot. Как вернуть пользователю сообщение об ошибке?

Tags: java, spring, исключения, spring-boot

Я сознательно загружаю большой файл, чтобы получить исключение.
контроллер обработки:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces={"application/text; charset=UTF-8"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(
        @RequestParam("uploadfile") MultipartFile uploadfile) throws Exception {
    String fileName =  storageService.uploadFile(uploadfile);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(fileName, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

у меня есть глобальный перехватчик:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler implements ErrorViewResolver {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalControllerExceptionHandler.class);

    private static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {MultipartException.class})
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request, MultipartException ex) {
        LOG.error("Exception in uploadFile at request " + request.getRequestURL(), ex);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        LOG.error("Exception at request " + request.getRequestURL(), e);
        mav.addObject("timestamp", new Date());
        mav.addObject("error", e.getMessage());
        mav.addObject("path", request.getRequestURL());
        return mav;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveErrorView(HttpServletRequest request, HttpStatus httpStatus, Map<String, Object> map) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        LOG.error(map.toString());
        /**
        timestamp --- Fri Oct 20 09:46:58 MSK 2017
        status --- 404
        error --- Not Found
        message --- /hudo
        path --- /hudo
         **/
        map.forEach(mav::addObject);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

который перехватывает Исключение MultipartException

```
2017-10-23 14:44:13.635 ERROR 15680 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.web.GlobalControllerExceptionHandler   : Exception in uploadFile at request http://localhost:8080/painter/uploadFile

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field uploadfile exceeds its maximum permitted size of 3145728 bytes.
```

так вот, клиенту сообщение и статус не передаётся (вызов был по ajax). Ответ получил такой:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/painter/uploadFile net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
 статус - 0  text - undefined
```

как мне получить ответ из из перехватчика?